# Line break in mathtt

Tags: math-mode, formatting

I want to display text in the mathtt font in two separate lines, but the following doesn't work

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\title{Scratch}

$$\mathtt{Say\ hello} \newline \mathtt{to\ my\ little\ friend}$$

\end{document}
```

It's not working if I replace `\newline` by `\\` nor if I have a single `\mathtt{}`. The result in all cases is as if there is no `\newline` or `\\`.

I need my text to be formatted this way to look like JEdit code for the theorem prover Isabelle. If you have any other suggestions for how to do this I'll be more than happy to hear.

Comment: unrelated to your question, but please have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of how the result should look like? If the output should look like code, maybe the `listings` package is more suitable then a math environment?

Comment: `\newline` does not look healthy as well. Why using `math` here at all?

Comment: You can't use `\newline` in math displays to begin with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

[image]

There is no need for `\mathtt` here at all.

Either use `\ttfamily` in a TeX group, e.g. wrapping a `\begingroup...\endgroup` or define a special environment for this, say `tttt`, which forms its own group automatically, so both versions provide the same output, although the details in the background are different.

Leave an empty line to force a 'linebreak'

```
\documentclass{article}


\title{Scratch}

\newenvironment{tttt}{\ttfamily}{}
\begin{document}

\begingroup
\ttfamily Say hello 

to my little friend
\endgroup

\begin{tttt}
Say hello 

to my little friend
\end{tttt}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. I also need to include some math symbols like `\leq`, `\forall` `\cup` etc. Is there a neater way to do it that wrapping them with `$ $`?  Also, sometimes I need to have empty lines between the preceding and the following text, as with `$$ $$`.

Comment: @KyriakosKats: That's a different question. `$$...$$` is deprecated and should not be used any longer. Either use `\[....\]` instead or something like an `equation` or `align` environment.