# An environment for displaying math text in mathttt font with blank lines in between (Isabelle)

Tags: math-mode, fonts, environments, technical-environment

How can I create an environment that does the above? I want to be as close to Isabelle as possible(see picture). My best alternative is to define an environment as [in the answer to my other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/414837/line-break-in-mathtt) and insert `$ $`around every math character I use. Another big drawback of this solution is that in a block of text the first line is not alligned with the rest (like a paragraph in text mode in latex). Ideally I would like to be able to leave some blank space from the text before and after it (like `$$ $$` does) but also be able to text formatted this way inline (like `$`$ does). See the picture for the kind of result I want.[image]

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your question.  Your picture doesn't have any blank lines.  Or are you talking about some vertical spacing before and after the environment?

Comment: @Teepeemm thanks for noticing, I changed the code to look as it was supposed to.

Comment: Don't use $$...$$

Answer (score 1):

As [already said for your previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/414837/line-break-in-mathtt#comment1036484_414837), if you want to include code, a math environment might not be the best choice. I suggest the `listings` package instead. The appearance can be customised in many ways (syntax highlighting etc., see the documentation for details), but the basic usage would be like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\ttfamily,mathescape]
lemma inf_lim_larger_real:
    fixes M :: real and h :: "real $\Rightarrow$ real"
\end{lstlisting}    

\end{document}
```

[image]